# How to output progress indicator instead of the actual file contents

Tags: java

I have the following method the reads text file:

```
public static void readFile(String path) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine); // Progress indicator!
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My file is really large ~ 700MB, I would love to be able to print progress indicator or percentage instead of printing the actual file on the console which really does not look good. Something probably like this:

```
========================================================== 100%
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23167319/how-to-use-java-progress-bar-while-read-a-text-file could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change your `System.out.println` with progress. But for that you need couple of things.

1. Get the file size using `File` object i.e.

   File f = new File (path);
   double fileSize = f.length();
   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
2. Now inside the `while` loop. Everytime you read string you have to do something like this

   int percentRead = 0

   while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

   ```
   double bytesRead += (sCurrentLine.getBytes().length);

   int newPercentRead = (int)((bytesRead/fileSize) * 100);

   while (percentRead <= newPercentRead){

       System.out.print("#");

       percentRead++;

   }
   ```

   }

**Its not tested, so you might have to tweak it around**.

Comment: Thank you ... I will try it